# why shouldReceive method not recognize in Laravel unit test?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, intelephense

I need to test unit my service in Laravel app. When i writing this code:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Http\Requests\LoginUserRequest;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use Mockery;
use Mockery\MockInterface;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class AuthServiceTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     */
    public function corretLoginUserTest(): void
    {
        $loginUserRequest = Mockery::mock(LoginUserRequest::class);
        $loginUserRequest->shouldReceive('input')->with('email')->andReturn('kowal@gmail.com');
        $loginUserRequest->shouldReceive('input')->with('password')->andReturn('kowal12@');

        $user = new User();
        $userRepository = Mockery::mock(UserRepository::class);
        $userRepository->shouldReceive('findByEmail')->once()->with('test@example.com')->andReturn($user);
        $userRepository->shouldReceive('comparePassword')->with('password123', $user)->andReturn(true);
        $userRepository->shouldReceive('createToken')->with($user)->andReturn($user->createToken('token')->plainTextToken);
    }
}
```

I have errors, because my Visual Studio Code tell me in words `shouldReceinve` below line `$user = new User()`

```
Undefined method 'shouldReceive'.intelephense(1013)
<?php
public function shouldReceive(...$methodNames);
Set expected method calls
```

How i can solve this problem. Please help me, because I need to test my service.

Comment: You test is not executing anything as of now, secondly you error clearly seems to be from vs code console or similar what happens if you run it in the console?